# Stored Procedure multi-issue

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have the following tables:

- image_sources
- character_trait_annotations
- character_traits
- characters

(and tables that are not pertinent to this problem). I am trying to use a stored procedure that looks for an `ImageURL` in `image_sources` where `AnnotationID` is equal to the one fetched from the code at random. That `AnnotatonID` belongs to `character_trait_annotations` table, which also has a `CharacterID` and a `CharacterTraitID`. The `CharacterID` is in `characters` table, which has `CharacterName`, and the `CharacterTraitID` is in `character_traits`, which has `CharacterTraitName`.

The code is to call the stored procedure with `$character`, `$trait` (which are `CharacterName`, `CharacterTraitName`, respectively), and attempt to fetch the `ImageURL` for it.

**The stored procedure**

The SQL code for the procedure is as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getImageURL(IN charName VARCHAR(35), IN traitName VARCHAR(100))
    BEGIN
        SELECT ImageSourceURL FROM image_sources WHERE 
            AnnotationID = (SELECT AnnotationID FROM character_trait_annotations WHERE CharacterID = 
                (SELECT CharacterID FROM characters WHERE CharacterName = charName) AND CharacterTraitName = 
                (SELECT CharacterTraitID FROM character_traits WHERE CharacterTraitName = traitName)
            );
    END;
```

However, when I call the procedure from PHP, I get this error: `Unable to call stored procedure: Unknown column 'CharacterTraitName' in 'where clause'`. I was able to create the stored procedure without complaint on the active server.

I check this procedure locally, on my own machine('s version of the database, in phpMyAdmin), by trying to create the stored procedure there to see what is going on, and I get this error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7`

I even tried to enclose the column names and the table names with backticks, and it is telling me the same thing. What is wrong with this?

Comment: Quote it `WHERE CharacterTraitName = 'traitName'` since it's a string. Also `WHERE CharacterName = 'charName'`

Comment: Variable names have to be quoted?

Comment: Indeed they do. If it were an `int`, *ah*, now that's another story. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, and it still doesn't work: http://dinotator.biokdd.org/ResearchProject/stuffNotReadyToBeActive/
http://dinotator.biokdd.org/ResearchProject/loadAppData.php

Comment: Darn it. I had good expectations from that. Well Mike, I don't know what else it could be.

Comment: Is there an alternate query to what I used (that does the same thing)?

Comment: I couldn't say Mike. If I were an SQL guru I could. But this looks to me like you'd need to use a JOIN.

Comment: What is everything that could be going wrong (starting with how my tables are set up)? 

I was able to get this query to work: 
`SELECT `AnnotationID` FROM `character_trait_annotations` WHERE `CharacterID` = 
    (SELECT `CharacterID` FROM `characters` WHERE `CharacterName` = "Iron Man")`
but, as soon as I put on the AND condition, the problem pops up again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out; /* by "I", I mean a friend of mine */

**OK, so what did you do?**

I didn't have access to phpMyAdmin, MySQLConnect, or any other of those database editors, so I had to attempt making one of my own: http://dinotator.biokdd.org/ResearchProject/tableViewer.php . Right now, the only thing that works is the dropdown menu to select the tables.

I didn't have access to this up until today, and when I asked my friend, and he asked for a way to see the database, I gave him that. The problem he pointed out (and I should have seen) was the second condition in the subquery: `CharacterTraitName = 
                (SELECT CharacterTraitID FROM character_traits WHERE CharacterTraitName = traitName)` The stupid mistake that was made was trying to check for equality between `CharacterTraitName` and `CharacterTraitID`. Furthermore, `CharacterTraitName` column didn't exist in `character_trait_annotations`.

echo 'I feel dumb.';